# 22.04 External monitors turn off/go to sleep when laptop is suspended, while all settings are set to disabled

Tags: gnome, suspend, lock-screen

I use my (work) laptop always with the lid closed connected with a dock and 2 monitors (one monitor directly connected to HDMI another plugged into the dock with HDMI) this works fine.
But when i suspend my laptop, it goes into the locked screen (where you type in your password to regain access) and both my monitors, in turn, go to sleep. On any activity like pressing space bar the monitors are again in turn woken, during this period of both my monitors being black, i can already type in my password but i would like to prevent the monitors from going to sleep all together.

I have already went on searched to check several settings such as lock screen after suspend and privacy screen settings that would turn my screen blank, power settings are all set to disabled or timers on 2 hours (if disabled option is unavailable) everything is set to disabled, but it still happens, i've rebooted and re-logged multiple times after making changes, but no effect.

(Imaged on these settings)

[Settings > Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yJoi.png)

[Settings > Power](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLzZd.png)

[Settings > Privacy > Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFnZ8.png)

Here are some more settings i applied to try and make it work:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

I've only been using Linux (Pop OS specifically) for a year, so i don't have a lot of experience with these kinds of "bugs" where settings don't get applied propperly.

I hope this question is clear enough and would like to get some suggestions of what could be broken or happening.

Answer (score 0):

The monitors decide whether to enter stand-by mode or not by themselves, based on whether they are receiving a video signal or not.

If you want your monitors not to enter stand-by mode, then you have to keep sending them some signal, and you can only do that by not suspending your laptop.